# Old rewrite rules, how to change domain

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms

It's been a while I don't use the `<rewrite>` rules from [UrlRewrite](https://github.com/sethyates/urlrewriter) plugin and this is **driving me nuts**...

What I'm trying to accomplish is to redirect users that go to:

```
http://portals.presentkorttorget.se/GetRelationPdf.ashx?relationId=904
```

send them to

```
http://www.presentkorttorget.se/GetRelationPdf.ashx?relationId=904
```

**only the** `portals` **change to** `www` and I was trying to avoid make the redirect in .NET, compile and publish the entire site again.

What I've tried was:

```
<rewrite>
    <rule name="PDF redirect to parent shop" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="portals\.(([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+))$/GetRelationPdf\.ashx\?$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{R:1}/GetRelationPdf.ashx?{R:2}" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

as well some variants from the regular expression that I tested using http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

To redirect on sub domains as you want to do, you have to use conditions:

```
<rule name="PDF redirect to parent shop" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^GetRelationPdf\.ashx$" />
  <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="portals\.(([a-z]+)\.([a-z]+))$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:1}/GetRelationPdf.ashx" />
</rule>
```

This rule will check that the `HTTP_HOST` starts with `portals.` and contains 2 groups  separated by a `.` of at least on letter.
It will check as well that the requested path is `GetRelationPdf.ashx` (case insensitive).

In the redirect, the back reference is using `{C:1}`, taking the information from the conditions and the query string is by default append when a redirect is triggered.